# Passenger just showing directory in Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, apache2, passenger

I am trying to use Passenger to deploy a rails app on Ubuntu with Apache. I've followed pretty much every guide I could find on configuring Passenger with Apache/Ubuntu. However, when I go to the site, I just see the actual file directories and not the running version of the application. If i switch to the /public directory I just see the public directory when I go to the site. I can start and stop the rails server by calling `rails s` without getting any errors, but still am not able to see the running version of the application. Does anyone ran into similar problems? Is there a good starting point anyone could suggest I look at? I'm not sure if the problem is with apache or passenger.

Apache config

```
 LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.9/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
 PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby
 PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.9
 PassengerMaxPoolSize 10
 <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName http://www.myapp.com/
     DocumentRoot /var/www/myapp/current/
<Directory /var/www/myapp/current/public>
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

When I restart apache, I get a message stating `[Sun Nov 06 14:43:48 2011] [warn] module passenger_module is already loaded, skipping` I'm not sure if this is an error or is normal.

### Update

When I run `find / -name 'mod_passenger.so'` I get two locations: 
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.9/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_passenger.so

### Update 2

I have several passenger.config files

```
 /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/passenger.conf
 /etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.conf
 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.9/debian/passenger.conf
```

Each of the passenger.conf files has the following:

```
 <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
      PassengerRoot /usr
      PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby
 </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put following in apache config file

```
<Directory /var/www/myapp/current/public>
    Allow from all
    #Add following line
    Options +Includes -Indexes
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have mod_passenger.so symlinked into your apache2/mods-enabled directory. This would account for the double import.

Run

```
a2dismod mod_passenger.so
```

to remove any symlink, then restart Apache.